# Add poweroff to startup script

Tags: ubuntu, startup

I want to add `poweroff` to startup script `/etc/rc.local` (Ubuntu). It sounds odd or silly, the reason is I want to tease my friend for few minutes. I didn't tried it up to now.

Question:

1. Does the system really shutdown after startup?
2. If above case is true, how to stop it?
3. Is this really dangerous?

Comment: Pulling a prank is only funny if the person pranked upon can laugh about it. Just **assuming** that this works, if you or your friend do not know how to prevent the system from shutting down after the "novelty of the prank has faded", then you should not do this. In that case I would consider this dangerous, especially if your friend relies for work or other non-fun-only activities on his/her computer.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to prank him? :P

Comment: Okay, I understand. I'm not going to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a sleep command before poweroff.
For example:

`sleep 300; poweroff`

This way you will have 5 minutes before the poweroff. When you want to stop this, you can use these 5 minutes to login to the system and remove the poweroff command from the init script.

Another way would be to add `init=/bin/sh` to the kernel parameters upon booting (in the bootloader), when you want to stop this. Then only the kernel will be booted and no init scripts will be ran. You will endup in root shell. Since no scripts were ran you will need to remount your RootFS with RW, like this: `mount -o remount,rw /` then remove the init script, `sync` the FS and `reboot`.

I would use the first option, it's more safer if you don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, it will shutdown *as part of* the startup process. If there are services running on that box that don't like being forcibly shutdown while they're still starting up, it *might* be dangerous.

If you've successfully managed to insert an unguarded poweroff in the startup process, my "usual" way to fix it would be to boot into a live system from a rescue medium, mount the root partition, fix the startup script, remove all your files and access rights and think about a suitable punishment for you.